# Limit of a continuous angle

Tags: geometry, limits

Let $\gamma :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be an injective continuous map. Consider point $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ outside of the curve $\gamma$ and $A,B$ be the two ending points $\gamma(0)$, $\gamma(1)$ of the curve respectly. We fix point $M$ on the curve somewhere between $A$ and $B$. Now point $C$ on the curve moves continuously from $A$ to $B$ crossing $M$.

What can we say about both left and right limits of $\lim_{C \to M} \angle PCM$ ? (the angle is signed with respect to clockwork orienration).

Comment: I would guess they represent the angle at which the line segment PM crosses the image of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Line $CM$, as $C\to M$, tends to the line tangent at $M$ to the curve (provided that tangent exists, i.e. if $\gamma$ is differentiable). Hence $\angle PCM$ tends to the angle between line $PM$ and the tangent at $M$. Of course left and right limit give the two (different) angles formed by such lines.